# SharePoint Rounded Navigation Tabs/Colors

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-branding

I'm hoping to get some direction on the following scenario. I have some UI/UX design experience but not much in working with SharePoint 2013 branding. What I need to accomplish is the following:

Custom "tab" style navigation in the left hand and top of the page. These would look like folder tabs along the top, and on the left hand side they would only be rounded on the right corner. I understand that I need to edit the CSS but not sure how best to accomplish this considering some of our page requirements. We want to have the tabs along the top and left but each department's "page" is a different color theme.

[Example of tabs required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RAN.png)

Do I edit the Master Page CSS to get the rounded tabs look and then that is applied to each page, but that page keeps its color selection or do I have to do a CSS page for each page? For example, a department uses the color palette selection to assign their colors but the Master Page takes care of the tabs modification or do I have to do a Master Page for each department's page?

ANY direction would be a big help. I just need to deploy this as simply as possible but not sure how. -Thanks!

Comment: You should make your own CSS files and use Site Settings to apply them to the site.  One masterpage can have a different CSS files associated with it on each site.  Editing the existing CSS is not a good idea.    /_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

Comment: So the feature under Master Page to specify Alternate CSS URL should be pointed to a custom CSS file I develop with the modifications to the tab styles? I can store this custom CSS file in the Site Assets folder?

Comment: That or the style library are common locations, but really it can be stored in any document library.

Comment: Tried it but for some reason the CSS isn't being read when I used the Alternate CSS option.

Comment: This is the correct method for branding SharePoint.  You will need to make sure your CSS classes are specific and correct so that they are applied where expected.

Comment: Confirmed that the code is correct so it must be something on the server end. It doesn't render in IE, Firefox or Chrome. I'll keep looking but thanks.